# Trying to get a session token for Google Calendar using Python. Getting NonAuthSubToken error

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get a session token to use the Google Calendar API using the Python library. I'm using Django 1.2.1 and Python 2.7. The page basically has a "Login to Google Calendar" (see the auth_url variable below) link that requests the single use token. From what I can tell the single use token looks exactly as I would expect it to look (read: no error message from Google). But then when I upgrade to a session token I get a NonAuthSubToken error. Any ideas? Here's my code

```
def get_auth_url():
   next = SITE_DOMAIN + '/job/events'
   scope = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/'
   secure = True
   session = True
   calendar_service = gdata.calendar.service.CalendarService()
   return calendar_service.GenerateAuthSubURL(next, scope, secure, session)

@login_required
def get_events(request):
   auth_url = get_auth_url()
   if 'token' in request.GET:
      f = open('rsa.pem')
      rsa_key = f.read()
      f.close()
      single_use_token = gdata.auth.extract_auth_sub_token_from_url(SITE_DOMAIN + request.get_full_path(), rsa_key=rsa_key)
      calendar_service = gdata.calendar.service.CalendarService()
      calendar_service.auth_token = str(single_use_token)
      calendar_service.UpgradeToSessionToken()

   return render_to_response('getevents.html', {'useremail': request.user.email.replace('@', '%40'),'auth_url': auth_url}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: what authentication mechanism are you using?OAuth, AuthSub?

Comment: AuthSub. I didn't see an OAuth mechanism. Is that way easier? I used OAuth for Twitter awhile back and I had to write a lot of the code myself. Is Google's better?

Comment: google recommends using OAuth see here:http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: I think that might be the way I end up going. I'm going to start writing my OAuth code while I wait for people to answer my AuthSub issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the docs says:

> [***NonAuthSubToken***](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.service.html) *: Raised if a method
>   to modify an AuthSub token is used
>   when
>                        the user is either not authenticated or is
>   authenticated
>                        through another authentication mechanism.*

the user is authenticated? (second reason is eliminated as you are using `AuthSub`)

On the other hand, google recommends to use OAuth with it's Google Data APIs.

see here:[OAuth 1.0 for Web Applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html)

Comment: Thanks! Does that basically mean that the user needs to be logged into Google (which I am) or if that means my RSA key is invalid? I'm running off of localhost btw. I don't see that being an issue since the return URL is working but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: I got OAuth working and it turned out to be a lot less painful than my experience with Twitter's OAuth. So that's definitely good news. Don't quite know what the issue with AuthSub was but I think it had something to do with running it on localhost and Google was trying to verify my domain. Oh well, OAuth worked. Thanks again!